# Running Magento 1.9.2.2 - Customers cannot login - if reset password email sent, frame at link is blank

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.2.2, ce-1.9.2.4

I am running Magento CE 1.9.2.2, and today a customer notified us that they cannot login, or retrieve their password.

To test, I attempted to login with a customer account, it just refreshes the login page, and shows the same login/password space.

If I attempt to reset a password, it sends the email, but when you click on the link in the email the frame is blank that would load the reset form.

I have also edited app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php and uncommented the  Mage::logException($e); call and then checked the /var/log/exception.log file and it is blank.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have had the same problem, the answer is that your theme does not supply a variable called `form_key`.

Just as stated above I have to add:

`<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" />`

to the following files:

```
/app/design/frontend/default/template-name/template/customer/form/login.phtml
/app/design/frontend/default/template-name/template/customer/form/register.phtml
/app/design/frontend/default/template-name/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml
/app/design/frontend/default/template-name/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the above information is correct and good to know, just wanted to add a little more information here as a follow up for anyone reading this in the future. To fix my issue I needed to do a little more as I had updated to 1.9.2.4 after I posted this question. I had further login and checkout issues that were caused by a problem with the checkout.xml file in my theme, as the theme was written based on a previous version of Magento, probably back somewhere in the 1.6 range. Fix that worked for me provided below.

The fix:

needed to change the line in checkout.xml in the theme from:

```
<block type="checkout/onepage_payment_methods" name="checkout.payment.methods" as="methods" template="checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml">
```

to:

```
<block type="checkout/onepage_payment_methods" name="checkout.payment.methods" as="methods" template="checkout/onepage/payment/info.phtml">
```